# Concrete version of KKL Theorem

Tags: boolean-functions, combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

The Kahn–Kalai–Linial (KKL) Theorem says that for any balanced Boolean function $f:\{−1,1\}^n→\{−1,1\}$ we have $\max_i {\bf Inf}_i(f) = \Omega\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$. I am looking for a concrete version of this theorem that holds for all $n$. What is the tightest concrete version known?

Comment: I mean, the bound $\Omega\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$ does hold for all $n$, provided the implicit constant is small enough. Can't you just work through a proof of the KKL theorem and keep track of the constant? It might be a pain, but should be straightforward.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible, but I suspect this is already well-known in the literature and if so I would like to cite it (and avoid repeating work!)

Answer (score 5):

See Exercise 9.30 of Ryan O'Donnell's *Analysis of Boolean Functions* book [1]: for any $f\colon\{-1,1\}^n\to \{-1,1\}$,
$$
\mathbf{MaxInf}[f]\geq \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{Var}[f]\cdot \frac{\ln n}{n} (1-o(1))
$$
and what's in the $o(1)$ should be easy to figure out from the subquestion (b) of the exercise.

[1] O'Donnell, R. (2014). *Analysis of Boolean Functions*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9781139814782. See also [arXiv:2105.10386](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.10386).